# Excel VBA code generates emails but crashes Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

This code below creates (it does not send because they need visual verification) several emails (about 60) with 2 attachments, one is 209KB pptx ( I compressed it down as far as I could) and an .xlsb file (30Kb - 700kb depending).
Text is in HTML just cause we require some highlighting. I thought this would be better than calling a template out of outlook but if thats wrong let me know, I cant find any info about that.

The issue is while it will generate all the emails and attach all the files, it freezes my outlook to the point I have to close everything and restart from the task manager. I have waiting on it for over an hour to see if it works but it just generates the emails and then freezes. I can see the emails through my taskbar but i can't select them or my outlook inbox.

Any idea how to over come this?

```
Sub email()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MailMessage As String
Dim CusName As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call getemails


MailMessage = "<HTML><BODY> Hello, <br><br>" _
        & "Attached you will find your trailing 12 month (TTM) margin leak 
report which was discussed on the Best Practices call in August. (Deck from 
meeting attached as well)<br><br><br>" _
        & "<li> Tab 1 shows margin leak by item<br><br>" _
        & "<li>Tab 2 shows margin leak by vendor then by item<br><br>" _
        & "<li>Tab 3 is data tab where you can see all the data<br><br>" _
        & "Tab 1 and 2 includes a filter at the top so you can look at or 
exclude specific PCATs.<br><br>" _
        & "<b>Key definitions of fields on data tab:</b><br><br>" _
        & "<li>Base Price, Base Cost, Base Margin – Price, Cost and Margin 
dollars prior to margin leak<br><br>" _
        & "Thank you,<br><br>" _


Lastrow = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastrow
Set olApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")

If olApp Is Nothing Then

Set olApp = CreateObject(Class:="outlook.application")

End If

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    .To = Cells(i, 2).Value
    .Subject = Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & " - Margin Leak - " & Cells(i, 
1).Value
    .display
    .HTMLBody = MailMessage
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Linking_Files\Best Practices Margin Leak.pptx")
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\Desktop\June\" & Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsb")

End With

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows are you working with here?

Comment: Why do you create/get and destroy the Outlook application within your loop instead of outside it?

Comment: RE: how many rows: around 60 it will be variable between 40 and 80 depending on the month. Each row is a new email,

Re: Create and destroy: kinda a novice to email procedures, that was how i got it to execute without error every time, can't recall the error that was like 2 days ago haha, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Try these two: (1.) `For i = 1 To 10` instead of  Lastrow and (2.) delete `Set olMail = Nothing` and `Set olApp = Nothing`.

Comment: @Vityata: when you say 10, do you mean just make it a standard number like 80, in case there are 80 rows. We may have over 150 at some point? Why would lastrow cause an error in outlook?

Comment: @JoshuaToliver - I mean that is is a good idea to try with some small number to see whether the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @vityata - no the code works, tested with 20 emails. It is something about having to open the 60ish emails with data and html formating, I ran it with and without the set olMail and set olApp = to nothing, no difference, still crashed excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of memory issue, when it relies on the amount of email you generate.
Add a save and a close into your loop to avoid getting out of memory.

For my version of Excel (2010) the following worked fine reducing memory usage:

```
With olMail
   .To = Cells(i, 2).Value
   .Subject = Format(MonthName(Month(Now))) & " - Margin Leak - " & Cells(i, 1).Value
   .display
   .HTMLBody = MailMessage
   .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\u\Desktop\test.xls")
   .Save
   .Close 1
End With
```

Comment: What does .close 1 mean?

Comment: @JoshuaToliver more detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-close-method-outlook). Note that you can simplify `.Save` and `.Close 1` to just `.Close olSave`.

Comment: Okay, I added that code in with something else, I added a send feature depending if there is a recipient (email recipient) in my list and it will save as a draft if there is no email recipient. Now I get an error on .send

Comment: @JoshuaToliver if the question has been answered you may accept the answer. Regardless of acceptance, if you have a new question generate a new question post.

Comment: .Close olSave does not worked for my excel version 2010. thats why i used .save and .close 1